# Password validation using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a password with the following rules:

- Must have at least eight characters.
- Must contain ONLY letters and digits.
- Must contain at least two digits.

So far I wrote this code:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z] (?=(.*\d){2}) {8,}
```

Im not sure why the passwords I enter returns invalid although it follows the rules.

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: Disallowing all non alphanumeric chars seems like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that spaces are meaningful in a regex pattern, so you require at least 8 spaces at the end. There are no anchors in the regex, so the length limitation might not work even if you write a correct pattern. So far, this will match an alphanumeric, a space that is followed with 2 occurrences of any 0+ chars followed with a digit, but since there is space with `{8,}` quantifier, this pattern will never match anything.

You need

```
^(?=.{8})[a-zA-Z]*(?:\d[a-zA-Z]*){2}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98HQBI/1)

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{8})`  - at least 8 chars
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more letters
- `(?:\d[a-zA-Z]*){2}` - 2 sequences of:

  - `\d` - a digit (may be replaced with `[0-9]`)
  - `[a-zA-Z]*` - zero or more letters
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

Alternatively, you may use

```
^(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98HQBI/2)

Here, `(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d){2})` will require at least 2 occurrences of 0+ letters followed with a digit in the string and `[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}` will match 8 or more alphanumeric chars.